# Campaign Ads (House Ads)

Tags: android, admob, ads

my admob ads works perfectly (mediation by admob, running like 7 activities where i have these ads) but when i started campaign in one of my activity with one simple AD (320x50) it doesnt show. Tried every type of campaign noone worked.

Is there anything what i need to do? Something in code? or in Admob settings (except cpm, chose which activity, type of AD etc... already done that). I was searching for this problem the whole week but didnt find any succes.

If someone could help me it will be awesome because there is no support on AdMob  except of FAQ which tells you nothing.

Comment: Please, post some source code, where you are displaying that Admob. I think, that one of the most typical case, where this problem occurs is when there isn't enough space for that current advertisement. Check the whole log, not even for your app, list the whole logcat without filtering and Verbose level.

Comment: I tried difference size modul for Ads and Layouts and neither one works... I even tried create whole new activity and give full displey for Ads and it didnt work too

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample of code activity and layout:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tejbl_tlacitka"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >

                <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                    style="@style/bannerpozadi"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    ads:adSize="BANNER"
                    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4412963312739253/5142509411" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
 public class oAplikaciActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView mAdview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_oaplikaci);
        setTitle("O aplikaci");

        mAdview = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdview.loadAd(adRequest);
```